# How can I debug coc-tsserver to figure out why it can't find a definition?

Tags: coc.nvim, tsserver

I couldn't craft a `tsconfig.json` file that works with the aliases I have defined for both Parcel on `package.json` and storybook on `.storybook/main.js`.

How can I debug coc.nvim using coc-tsserver to understand how tsserver is resolving dependencies? I couldn't find a way to start the tsserver with `--traceResolution`.